# Encryption Transformer in Mule

Tags: encryption, mule

Please can anyone help me with encryption namespace and schema location in Mule 3.4.

I have this Configuration XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation" xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" version="EE-3.4.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd">


<encryption:config name="Encryption_PGP" defaultEncrypter="PGP_ENCRYPTER" doc:name="Encryption_PGP">
        <encryption:pgp-encrypter-config publicKeyRingFileName="./mule.gpg" secretKeyRingFileName="./secring.gpg" secretAliasId="3879972755627455806" secretPassphrase="mule1234" principal="test1"/>
</encryption:config>
<flow name="sdsd">

<encryption:encrypt config-ref="Encryption_PGP" doc:name="Encryption" using="PGP_ENCRYPTER" input-ref="#[message.payload]">
        <encryption:pgp-encrypter principal="fernando.martinez &lt;fernando.martinez@mulesoft.com&gt;" />
</encryption:encrypt>
</flow>
</mule>
```

But its giving me this error: The prefix "encryption" for element "encryption:config" is not bound.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To use the the message processors from the **encryption** namespace you need to install the [Anypoint Enterprise Security module](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Anypoint+Enterprise+Security)

You can find more informations about how to use it [here](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Mule+Message+Encryption+Processor)

That said this is an EE only feature, so if you don't have an EE license you should probably use the [PGP security](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/PGP+Security) instead